# How to assign a value to a property in django

Tags: python, django

i have a new property in my model however I'd like to assign a test value in it for my test script.

this is my code:

models.py

```
mycode = models.UUIDField(null=True)

@property
def haveCode(self):
   if self.mycode == uuid.UUID('{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}'):
      return False
   else
      return True
```

and this is the test script that i am working on. I wanted to have a test value for haveCode:

```
test = Test()
test.mycode = uuid.UUID('{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}')
test.save()

checkTest = Test()

#this is only to pass the test
#delete this when start coding
checkTest.haveCode = True

assertEqual(test.haveCode, True)
```

however I got an error in `checkTest.haveCode = True` since this is just a property and not an attribute.

how to assign `True` to it? I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 'mock' that property using the mock library

```
from mock import patch, PropertyMock

@patch.object(Test, 'haveCode', new_callable=PropertyMock)
def myTest(test_haveCode_mock):
    test_haveCode_mock.return_value = True
    checkTest = Test()
    assertEqual(checkTest.haveCode, True)
    patch.stopall()  # when you want to release all mocks
```

Comment: should I install mock, it says no module named 'mock'

Comment: you use haveCode - python PEP8 convention is all lowercase def names spaced with underscores - so have_code is better, but I updated :)

Comment: to install mock ```pip install mock```

Comment: is there any other way that I wouldn't have to install it because this is only for one time testing... But i really appreciated this

Comment: @JamesReid I would definitely install it. It takes 30 seconds to install, if that. And you will use it a lot in testing. It will also: 1. speed up your tests 2. let you exert better control over tests. 3. Reduce test setup code by just mocking/stubbing whatever you like